# RTMFP and peer-to-peer ports/firewalls

Tags: firewall, rtmfp

Trying to implement RTMFP for video/audio conferencing app.

The developers have cited this issue:

[RTMFP and firewall/NAT traversal options](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1140620)

We have openRTMFP (cumulus) server up and running. We could have this sat inside or outside the company network (outside for the "cloud" service, inside for the "local instance" service). But this firewall/NAT issue looks a show stopper.

Has anybody over come this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an answer like "It is possible to use RTMFP inside a company network", then yes, it is possible. A little bit complicated, but possible.

We set up a TURN server to allow Flash clients to communicate with the outside world (contacting Adobe's servers or other peers). This server must have access to the internet, of course.

That's not all : UDP should be allowed inside your LAN and between your desktop PC and this TURN server (mostly firewalls rules). No need to precise a port since you can't know which port will be used.

Finally : telling the Flash client to use our RTMFP TURN server. You should write this line in the mms.cfg file on Windows 7 :

```
RTMFPTURNProxy = your.turn.server.org
```

You can also create a .bat file to be executed with admin rights (that's what we did), containing this command :

```
echo RTMFPTURNProxy = your.turn.server.org > %WINDIR%\sysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which TURN server or implementation are you using?